# Internet Explorer does not talk with django dev server

Tags: django, internet-explorer, localhost

I am running the python development server locally , like so:

```
python .\manage.py runserver
```

This works fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari, but when I try it with Internet Explorere (9, 8, 7) the server will not interact with the browser - actions like log in will take forever and eventually fail.

Essentially anything that is not a simple static template (sometimes not even that) will not load in IE (but loads fine in FF/Chrome)

My Environment:

- Windows 7 (x64)
- Aptana
- Python v2.7.2
- django v1.3

Update: This does not happen when I explicitly define the server IP address, like so:

```
python .\manage.py runserver 192.168.1.123:8000
```

Any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: What URL are you trying to navigate to?

Comment: please post the page source (the source that the browser sees, not your django source).

Comment: When running the built-in server on Linux and running Windows in a VM, I've seen slow response times from IE. Are you doing all your development on Windows?

Comment: @Jack M: Root works fine, but when I go to accounts/login it will hang.

Comment: @akonsu: It does not display the page source, it will time out before it gets any data.

Comment: @Brandon: Not running in a VM. Windows7 x64, Aptana, 32-bit python.

Comment: Try looking in Fiddler? If your web server is single-threaded, then IE9's background connection feature will break things.

Comment: @EricLaw - This also happens in IE8 and IE7. Is there a way to disable the IE9's background connection?

Answer (score 1):

Two guesses:

1. If you're developing on Windows and pointing your browser at localhost:8000, try 127.0.0.1:8000 instead. I've had that issue with IE9 before.
2. If you're working with a VM (I'm asking because IE7,8,9 won't all run on the same OS) you need to point to the host machine IP, since localhost would be the local IP of the VM itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the following to your httpd.conf.  I've had issues before with IE not submitting POST data.

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" ssl-unclean-shutdown
MaxKeepAliveRequests 1
```